# VLC: keep it open to be faster

Tags: ubuntu, record, vlc, rtsp

I'm recording a stream this way:

`rtsp://teams:teams@10.200.0.95/img/media.sav --rtsp-tcp  --no-sout-audio --rtsp-
caching=0 --sout "#std{mux=mp4,access=file,dst=cam-3.mp4}`

It takes 1 second to start, and I need it to be faster. I'm wondering whether 
it's possible to keep VLC open and communicate with it to start 
recording faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start VLC without starting your recording and control it through one of [it's various interfaces](http://wiki.videolan.org/Interfaces).  Probably **[rc](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aModules/rc)** is probably the one you want for this task.

If you start vlc with something like this:

```
vlc -I rc --rc-host localhost:10000
```

you can send it commands with netcat like this:

```
 echo "your_command_goes_here" | netcat localhost 10000
```

Also, depending how you're doing this, a lot of programming languages have wrappers for vlc which might make your life easier:

- http://wiki.videolan.org/Libvlc
- http://wiki.videolan.org/Developers_Corner

Comment: BTW don't you know the command i need to use? Because the next command doesn't work: echo "rtsp://teams:teams@10.200.0.95/img/media.sav --rtsp-tcp --no-sout-audio --rtsp- caching=0 --sout '#std{mux=mp4,access=file,dst=cam-3.mp4}'" | netcat localhost 10000

Answer (score 2):

check out [this blog](http://getluky.net/2006/04/19/vlcs-awesome-rc-interface/) with a nice description of all the commands available.

Your command would be "add rtsp://teams....". VLC must be started with all your other options before though.